# jQuery on() event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is the following delegated across both `<div>` tags? ie: one or two event handlers? I need to capture the `data-id` on the event.delegateTarget. This is simple when attaching to each of the `<div>` tags but I may have 20 or so of these. Guessing not a big deal either way, but I would like a better understanding.

The jQuery Docs state that if I provide the `selector` for the `on` method, it is delegated but my scenario seems to be a slightly different case where I am attaching to multiple elements. Is there a way I can see the resulting event handlers using my browsers debugger tools?

If I attach my handler to the `document`, is there any easy way I can capture the containing `div`? My document is quite a bit more complicated than the example and I can't simply rely on the fact that the `div` and associated `data-id` is a direct parent of the `input` elements.

```
$(".target").on("change", "input", function (event) {
...
});

<div class="target" data-id="123">
    <input type="checkbox" name="alpha" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="alpha" value="2" />
</div>

<div class="target" data-id="789">
    <input type="checkbox" name="beta" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="beta" value="4" />
</div>
```

Comment: But you *can* rely on the `div` being an ancestor of the `input` element. You could simply use `$(this).closest('[data-id]')` to select the `div`.

Answer (score 3):

It's one handler function that'll be called for "change" events on `<input>` elements in either of the two `<div>` elements.

The *real* event handler is a jQuery internal thing, that examines the event target and dispatches appropriately.

If you attach to the `<body>`, you'd do this:

```
$('body').on('change', '.target input', function() { ... });
```

From the handler, `this` will be the `<input>` and you can use `.closest('.target')` to find the container.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's two separate delegations, if that's what you're asking. A separate reference to the handler function is attached to each of the two `.target` divs, and each one handles the events triggered by their own pair of checkboxes.

If you bind to a common ancestor of both divs, you can always find the containing div by using `$(this).closest('.target')`, as Pointy suggested.